# Question about variable storage in memory

Tags: c, memory

Such a code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    short int x = 2;
    short int* px = &x;
    short int y = 3;
    short int* py = &y;
    
    printf("px\t%p\n", px);
    printf("px+1\t%p\n\n", px+1);
        
    printf("py\t%p\n", py);
    printf("py+1\t%p\n\n", py+1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs something like this:

px      0061FF16

px+1    0061FF18

py      0061FF14

py+1    0061FF16

This code however:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    short int x = 2;
    short int* px = &x;
    int y = 3;
    int* py = &y;
    
    printf("px\t%p\n", px);
    printf("px+1\t%p\n\n", px+1);
        
    printf("py\t%p\n", py);
    printf("py+1\t%p\n\n", py+1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Prints this:

px      0061FF16

px+1    0061FF18

py      0061FF10

py+1    0061FF14

My question: why is x's pointer 6 bytes higher than y's in second code? And not for example 4?

Comment: Alignment, probably.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to put variables in any order in memory it lijes to. Especially variables with different sizes and alignments might not be stored in same sequence as you put them in your code.

Comment: You should maybe better ask why x and y are only 2 bytes apart in first code, while there is another pointer variable in between.

Comment: `int` typically needs to be 4-byte aligned, while `short int` can be 2-byte aligned, but pointers are (on 64-bit ISA) 8-byte aligned, though this entirely depends on your ISA. Any expectations you develop here can be completely invalidated by some other ISA where the rules are different.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, variables may be stored in memory however your compiler feels like storing them. If you have:

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    // ...
}
```

Then the memory for `c` might be "first" or "last". Don't make assumptions based on how you've declared the variables, and definitely don't write code around any such assumptions.

As for why the pointers are offset by 6 bytes, a `short` is 2 bytes, and adding 6 gets 8 bytes, which is a reasonable amount if you compiler is aligning such values to 8 bytes for more efficient access.

The only way you can be sure of memory arrangement is if you have an array of values, and even then, if it's an array of structs, those structs may internally be padded to a certain alignment.